# How can I rotate the two endpoints of a line around the line's center in 3d?

Tags: 3d, mathematics, rotation, quaternion

The object is a capsule. I have the position of the object vector3, and the orientation of the object, a quaternion. I want to construct a line which goes through the middle of the capsule with the two endpoints of the line being the top and bottom.

The capsule can be rotated in all 3 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your capsule is aligned along the y axis, it could look something like this:

```
top = centerPosition + orientation * (new Vector3(0, halfHeight, 0));
bottom = centerPosition + orientation * (new Vector3(0, -halfHeight, 0));
```

(Here I'm assuming `quaternion * vector` is evaluated as \$q v q^{-1}\$, rotating the vector by the quaternion)